# RegEx to catch anything and any whitespace or line-break

Tags: php, regex

I'm new to this thing of Regex..
But I'm trying to **scrape** this pattern:

```
{@if="$age< 18"}
deny
{else}
allow
{@/if}
```

So, I wrote this regex:

```
({@if=".*"}\s?)(.*\s*{else}\s*)(.*\s*{\@\/if}\s?)
```

Basically:

1st group: Starts with ***{@if="***, matches anything except for line terminators and end with ***"}***.

2nd group: matches anything (except for line terminators), then matches any amount of whitespace until find ***{else}*** literally.

3rd group: matches anything (except for line terminators), then matchesany amount of whitespace until find ***{@/if}*** literally

It seemed to work well. But If my string gets new whitespaces and then more text.. It doesn't match!

Just like this:

```
{@if="$age< 18"}
deny

deny!!!
{else}
allow



allow!!

<div class="allowDiv">Allow!</div>
{@/if}
```

I think I can see where I am wrong!
Both the second and third groups stop matching if there is more text (or html code) between the blanks (which may or may not come). But the point is that I can't find a solution that will keep it searching any text until it gets to {else} (in the case of group 2) and {@ / if} (in the case of group 3).

If anyone can help, I appreciate it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: It doesn't work! Because If I had another block of code using the same pattern, It will matches everything! :(

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/rJLsr7/1

Comment: lost `?` in the second case . And now? - https://regex101.com/r/rJLsr7/2

Comment: That's perfect! Why don't you put this as an answer? So I can choose it and you'll earn some points!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that maybe this expression might be desired:

```
({@if="[^"]+"})\s*(.*?{else}\s*)(.*?\s*{\@\/if})
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/83wpwc/1)

#### Test

```
$re = '/({@if="[^"]+"})\s*(.*?{else}\s*)(.*?\s*{\@\/if})/s';
$str = '{@if="$age< 18"}
deny

deny!!!
{else}
allow



allow!!

<div class="allowDiv">Allow!</div>
{@/if}

{@if="$age< 18"}
deny

deny!!!
{else}
allow



allow!!

<div class="allowDiv">Allow!</div>
{@/if}';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression "could" work if you specify the following:

- "s" - "Dot matches line breaks"
- "U" - "Lazy quantifiers"

Example usage

```
preg_match_all('%({@if=".*"}\s?)(.*\s*{else}\s*)(.*\s*{\@\/if}\s?)%sU', $subject, $result, PREG_SET_ORDER);
for ($matchi = 0; $matchi < count($result); $matchi++) {
    for ($backrefi = 0; $backrefi < count($result[$matchi]); $backrefi++) {
        # Matched text = $result[$matchi][$backrefi];
    } 
}
```